# Function call inside promise.all

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have passed a function (which returns a promise) inside `Promise.all` but I'm not getting the expected output

```js
function first() {
  Promise.all([fun, fun1, fun2])
    .then(function(values) {
      console.log(values);
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}

function fun() {
  return new Promise((res, re) => {
    res(console.log("dd"));
  });
}

function fun1() {
  return Promise.resolve(3);
}

function fun2() {
  return 2;
}

//calling function here
first();
```

Expected: `[dd,3,2]`

Actual: `[ [Function: fun], [Function: fun1], [Function: fun2] ]`

Comment: please view the image for the code

Comment: Put your code in the quesiton, not a comment.

Comment: Code must be IN the question itself, not as comment and not as image. See [ask]

Comment: Use [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to post executable code.

Comment: Don't post code as an image, post as text.

Comment: You have to actually call your functions and pass their return values in the array you pass to `Promise.all()`.  You are just passing the function references which never calls them.

Answer (score 3):

> I have passed a function (which returns a promise) inside Promise.all

Incorrectly. You should pass the promise returned from that function. So if *fun* returns a promise, instead of

```
Promise.all([fun, fun1, fun2])
```

you should do

```
Promise.all([fun(), fun1(), fun2()])
```